# wrong data send to php through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

this the code in ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var i = 0;
     while($($(".empleado")[i]).children('.id_empleado').html() != null){
      var  datas ='id_empleado='+encodeURIComponent($($(".empleado")
      [i]).children('.id_empleado').html())+'&i='+i;
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "descripcion_segundo.php",
      data: datas,
      async: false,
      success:  function (result) {
       $("#descripcion").append(result);
       }
      });
     }
    });
```

and this is the code in php(descripcion_segundo.php):

```
<?php
$flag = $_POST['i'];
$id_empleado = $_POST['id_empleado'];
echo "<a>" . $flag ." ".$id_empleado."</a>";
?>
```

the $flag take the value 1 the first time and again 1 in the second, then the loop ends.
why does it take value 1?, and twice?
the funny thing is that the same line defines i, the next one:

```
var  datas ='id_empleado='+encodeURIComponent($($(".empleado")
[i]).children('.id_empleado').html())+'&i='+encodeURIComponent(i);
```

,use i to get another value but this value is taken fine, meaning the value of i is 0 in this case.
Help!

Comment: Try using console.log(datas) in your javascript and double check the params sent to the script are fine.

Comment: Aren't you missing an `i++` somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't look like an AJAX request is actually needed here...

Comment: yes  i forgot the i++ but that's not the problem.

Comment: what do you mean i don't need ajax?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your datas object is incorrectly set. You should be doing something like this:

```
var  datas = { id_empleado : 'Your data' };
```